# vbscript entering full screen command offline

Tags: vbscript

Is there a command for vbscript that enters full screen?

Do I use hta? 
Here's the program so far. (Please don't mind the "imageopener.hta")

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "imageopener.hta"
WScript.Sleep 6000
dim ft
ft=inputbox("Hello! Type in anything to start the program!")

strName = InputBox("Please input your user name.")
Select Case LCase(strName)
    Case "imaisa"
        Msgbox "Welcome Shin Imai!"
    Case "knightrr"
        Msgbox "Welcome Riley Knight!"
    Case "walmerab"
        Msgbox "Welcome Andrew Walmer!"
        Msgbox "HERE'S YOUR SPECIAL COURSE ANDREW!!! www.pokemon.com"
    Case "admin"        
        strName = InputBox("Please input password")
        Select Case LCase(strName)
            Case ft
                Msgbox "Welcome Admin!"
            Case else
                Msgbox "You have inserted the wrong password. The program will now exit."
                WScript.Quit 1
        End Select
    Case else
        Msgbox "Invalid Username!"
        WScript.Quit 1
End Select
Msgbox "All right guys! Today we're going to learn about Colonialism so listen up!"
Msgbox "The nation state is a state that has a territory where mainly 1 nation lives. The state is a political entity; the nation is a cultural and/or ethnic entity."
Msgbox "BEFORE NATIONSTATES, Principalities existed being ruled mostly by a single royalty. JOT THIS DOWN ONTO YOUR NOTEBOOK!"
MsgBox "WILLIAM THE CONQUEROR: William I (William the Conqueror) was the first Norman King of England. AFter a struggle to establish power, in 1066, he launched the Norman Conquest of England. After success, the rest of his life was marked by struggles to consolidate his holdd over England and his continental lands and difficulties with his eldest sun."
MsgBox "Marriage was cheaper and much less disruptive to the people of principalities. However even in cases of marriage, misunderstandings developed, as was the case of Henry III and Catherine of Arigon."
MsgBox "Spices were important. The spice trade pre dated colonialism by thosands of years. Spices were used for PRESERVING FOOD, MEDICINES, and GOOD SMELLS."
MsgBox "Colonialism made many European speculators wealthy, it proved costly for others. It was even more costly for the natives of the colonized lands. This was true in Africa, and the Americas. It was not true in Asia because Asia was already civilized and had an economic organization. The only exception was India, which still lived on an agrarian society."
MsgBox "In Africa, historical tribal lands were divided among various European countries based on the location of natural resources and without regard for the ethnicity of the indigenous people. This practice went to Asia in the 20th century with the discovery of oil. (iraq, Syria, etc.)"
MsgBox "The local populations were devastated by diseases carried by europeans. Small Pox and Tuberculosis were among the diseases."
MsgBox "BIG WINNERS IN COLONIAL TRADE: royal families of the colonial powers of Europe and the great trading houses that were in their favor."

MsgBox "Large banking and insurance companies were needed to provide the capital and security necessary to promote trade and reduce risk. In 1688, Lloyds of London was formed to insure trading vessels and their cargo. They were among the largest insurers of slaves."
MsgBox "By the late 1700s, the Rothschild family had established banking houses across Western Europe, and by the early 1800s in the U.S."
MsgBox "In the tropical and subtropical areas of the americas, the indigenous peoples were removed from the lands and replaced with African Slaves. Example: Something that happened in Georgia removed Cherokees and Kreeks and placed them in Oklahoma, and replaced by African Slaves."
MsgBox "Sugar cane, indigo, and cotton were all labor intensive and required large number of slaves for production and processing."
MsgBox "In the mid 1700s, Scottish weavers devoloped a kind of durable fabric used for work clothes called jean cloth. The cloth was typically dyed blue. This created a large demand for cotton fiber and indigo dye."
MsgBox "Slavery was a brutal institution, yet owners did not care about their health. The slaves were typically worked to exhaustion and were severely disciplined if they messed up."
MsgBox "Slave women had to produce as many babies as possible, since each child represented the growth of the owner's initial investment. Most slave women did work while pregnant."
MsgBox "Men and women were sold like livestock never to see their family again."
MsgBox "Colonialism encouraged and created the horrible slave system. Many slaveholders mortgaged their slaves to buy more land. In either case, the slaves were bound to the banks."
MsgBox "The stability of the economic system depended on the institution of slavery."
MsgBox "There were a lot of losers in the economy as well. There were scammers such as John Law. John Law exaggerated the value of French holdings in North America from Louisiana to Quebec. (Known as Mississippi). He formed a company sold stock to wealthy european based on the exaggerated value, and used the money to gain the French Finances, and colonial trades across the world. When the true value of the stock was discovered, the values dramatically dropped eventually destroying his company which therefore costed the economy to crash."
result=MsgBox("Did natives benefit from Colonialism?", vbYesNo, "Question 1")
Select Case result
Case vbYes
    result=MsgBox("Were the natives moved to Oklahoma?", vbYesNo, "Question 2")
    Select Case result
    Case vbYes
        result=MsgBox("Was Langston's of London an insurance company?", vbYesNo, "Question 3")
        Select Case result
        Case vbYes
            MsgBox"You got 1 out of 3 questions correct! You should study more!"
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox"You got 2 out of 3 questions correct! What an average score!"
        End Select
    Case vbNo
        result=MsgBox("Was Langston's of London an insurance company?", vbYesNo, "Question 3")
        Select Case result
        Case vbYes
            MsgBox"Wow you got 0 correct. You MUST STUDY MORE!"
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox"You got 1 out of 3 questions correct! You should study more!"
        End Select
    End Select

Case vbNo
    result=MsgBox("Were the natives moved to Oklahoma?", vbYesNo, "Question 2")
    Select Case result
    Case vbYes
        result=MsgBox("Was Langston's of London an insurance company?", vbYesNo, "Question 3")
        Select Case result
        Case vbYes
            MsgBox"You got 2 out of 3 questions correct! What an average score!"
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox"You got all questions correct! Good job! You're prepared for your quiz!"
        End Select
    Case vbNo
        result=MsgBox("Was Langston's of London an insurance company?", vbYesNo, "Question 3")
        Select Case result
        Case vbYes
            MsgBox"You got 1 out of 3 questions correct! You should study more!"
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox"You got 2 out of 3 questions correct! What an average score!"
        End Select
    End Select
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a command for vbscript that enters full screen?

Errrmmm... no. (Whatever you mean with fullscreen for msgboxes, I'm afraid the answer will always be *no*).
To get any more control over your visual output, you might start to learn programming with e. g. *Visual Studio for Desktop*
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express